# Java downloading text file results in html code instead of text

Tags: java

When i download this text file [asdf.txt](https://alm.automic.com/jama/attachment/542/asdf.txt)
using apache commons-io:

`URL fileURL = new URL(urlMatcher.group(1));
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(fileURL, new File(fileName));`

it results in html code of a webpage instead of the

> I'm asdf the text file!

it should return.

printing the url as a string has this result:

> https://alm.automic.com/jama/attachment/542/asdf.txt

Please help me figure out the Java code for the POST Request needed in order to log in

> Host=alm.automic.com
>
> User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
>
> Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language=en-US,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate
>
> Referer=https://alm.automic.com/jama/login.req
>
> Cookie=JSESSIONID=CA14239217D0E54E913D17083F71724F; DWRSESSIONID=8nCO$BHWFA2282XF4fVYnmwl7Wk; jamaContourServerTime=1436778397165; jamaContourSessionExpiry=1436778397165
>
> Connection=keep-alive
>
> Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Content-Length=53
>
> POSTDATA=j_username=user&j_password=pass&submit=Login

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: http://puu.sh/iU4ja.png - looks like it actually is a web page. Does your program have some way of logging in?

Comment: @immibis if you try to click the link it will forward you to the file directly shouldn't that be enough to download it

Comment: @immibis never mind inspecting element helped me realize what you meant... still the html code is not the one of the site

Comment: If I click the link it sends me to a login page. It probably also sends your program to a login page, unless your program is somehow logged in.

Comment: Indeed, the file you refer to is 'hidden' behind a loginscreen for some site you are (presumably) already logged into.

Open a new private browsing session and go to that link and you'll see exactly what your program sees when it tries to download the file.

Comment: @Buurman i see what you mean can you help me figure out how to create the POST request for the site login i will update the main post with the Tampered POST request

Comment: @immibis well my program is not logged in in any way. How would i do that? i would prefer a POST request since i have the structure for it(see post)

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do the http connection, if anyone needs it:
Use following classes and something like Temper Data (Firefox addon) to find out GET/POST request Headers/Data and add it to following classes in a fashion something like this..

```
ArrayList<String> cookies = new ArrayList<String>(1);
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(link);

        // Request parameters and other properties.
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        httpGet.addHeader("Host", "alm.automic.com");
        httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0");
        httpGet.addHeader("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        httpGet.addHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        httpGet.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        if (cookies.size() > 1)
            httpGet.addHeader("Cookie",
                    cookies.get(cookies.size() - 1).split(";")[0]);
        httpGet.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

        // Execute and get the response.
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        Header[] responseHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();
        String location = "https://alm.automic.com/jama/login.req;";

        for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.length; i++)
        {
            if (responseHeaders[i].getName().equals("Set-Cookie"))
            {
                if (responseHeaders[i].getValue().split(";")[0].split("=")[0]
                        .equals("JSESSIONID"))
                    cookies.add(responseHeaders[i].getValue());
            }
            if (responseHeaders[i].getName().equals("Location"))
            {
                location = responseHeaders[i].getValue();
            }
        }
```